# ColdFusion custom tag calling cfmail as attibuteCollection and throwing error

Tags: coldfusion, structure, coldfusion-8, cfmail

I am trying this on CF 8.0.1, but failing. I am trying to pass a custom value to the custom tag, like this:

```
<cf_call ckmail="#{to='test@test.com',from='test@test.com',subject='Error reported',mailserver='mail.domain.com',username='1234',password='tested'}#">
```

In the custom tag call.cfm i have the following:

```
<cfparam name="attributes.ckmail" default="">
<cfmail attributecollection = "#attributes.ckmail#">
```

The error I am getting is:

> Invalid CFML construct found on line 11 at column 18. ColdFusion was looking at the following text: {

It is working good in CF9, but in CF8.0.1 (or previous version) it is failing with the above message.

---

> Code Update as of July 18th 2012

---

I tried using dan's Code but now i am facing a different issue, In my Custom Tag i am using like this

```
       <cfset emailSetting = StructNew()>
   <!--- loop our query string values and set them in our structure --->
   <cfloop list="#attributes.ckmail#" index="key" delimiters=",">
     <cfset emailSetting["#listFirst(key,'=')#"] = urlDecode(listLast(key,"="))>
   </cfloop>
   <cfdump var="#emailSetting#"><cfabort>
       <cfmail attributecollection = "#emailSetting#">
```

The above are my settings in the custom tag, i called it from my code as

```
       <cf_call ckmail="to=i@test.com,from=test@domain.com,subject='Error reported',
    server=mail.domain.com,username=test@domain.com,password=tes@,type=html">
```

The error now i am getting is "smtp" server is not defined,

if i add smtp details in cfadmin it works, may be it ignores values in the field i typed but it shows error when there is no smtp settings defined in the cfadmin too.

Answer (score 2):

The implicit structure should work in CF8.0.1 as you have it.

You can of course use code like the following to build your structure using the structNew() function:

```
<cfset mailArgs             = StructNew() />
<cfset mailArgs.to          = 'test@test.com' />
<cfset mailArgs.from        = 'test@test.com' />
<cfset mailArgs.subject     = 'Error reported' />
<cfset mailArgs.mailserver  = 'mail.domain.com' />
<cfset mailArgs.username    = '1234' />
<cfset mailArgs.password    = 'tested' />

<cf_call ckmail="#mailArgs#">
```

Can you post a more detailed error report from ColdFusion here so that we can help you find the exact location of the error? Or can you post more of the code?

Comment: This is the detailed report i get from the code, My Confusion lies when the CF9 executes this Process and in CF 8 it fails, I see you have declared a Struct in different manner and then Passing it to the cfmail tag, I want it tobe passed along the Custom Tag but do 
not want to declare separately and the again use the above written code in Custom tag as:<cf_call ckmail="#mailArgs#">, i want to pass the actual written above rather than evaluate it again here

Answer (score 0):

You're using the struct literal syntax in the ckmail attribute, which I think has changed behaviour between CF8 and CF9. I'd try creating a struct the old-fashioned way and see if that works.

Comment: so using the Structnew() right, Btw i am passing it in Custom tag so bit confused how that will work

Comment: it will just look like    <Cf_call ckmail=ckmail/>  It won't have any construtor syntax - that's all done ahead of time. Check out the first answer - Matt's example is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.... I wonder if the pound signs look odd to anyone else in the custom tag call? Stucture notation usually looks like this:

```
<cfset mystruct = {to='test@test.com',from='test@test.com',subject='Error reported',mailserver='mail.domain.com',username='1234',password='tested'}/>
```

The pound signs would cause CF to try and "do something" to merge the values (like when you do `<cfset z = #x+y#/>`  ... but leaving them off allows CF to "see" the constructor indicators (the curly braces).

But I'm not sure how a custom tag would behave in that instance. Have you tried calling it like so:

```
<cf_call 
 ckmail={to='test@test.com',from='test@test.com',subject='Error reported',mailserver='mail.domain.com',username='1234',password='tested'}/>
```

Or failing that - as has been suggested - set it up ahead of time as:

```
<cfset args = {to='test@test.com',from='test@test.com',subject='Error reported',mailserver='mail.domain.com',username='1234',password='tested'}/>
```

Then call:

```
<cf_call ckmail="#args#"/>
```

See if any of those work eh?

Comment: i tried all the way you said here, but still i am facing the same problem, i have updated my question please check, this time i am getting some different error "smtp is not defined"